# Free trading platforms for learning FIX protocol

Tags: algorithmic-trading, trading, fix-protocol

I'm learning the FIX protocol, I was a bit interested in this topic, do you know any free platforms, API FIX where I could connect for free, not as a company and start receiving orders, sending etc.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find tools, software libraries or other off-site resources are off-topic according to the [help/on-topic] guidelines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is FixSim which allows to connect for free for one hour per day.
Disclaimer: I've never tested it and am in no way affiliated with them.

https://www.fixsim.com/Pricing